# How to export DynamoDB and import to another aws account?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am doing an exercise using serverless model with services (cognito, api gateway, lambda, DynamoDB)
I want to backup DynamoDB to import to another AWS account (my customer's account)
I don't know what to do. Please help me! thank you

Comment: did you try https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-cross-account-migration/

Comment: Thanks for your support, Yeah i tried Data Pipeline solution, that only backup data. About table structure I used cloudformation.